# Django: Annotate two values of the most recent foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime

I'm actually using python 3.7 and Django 3.0.4.

I using in my app **models.py** like this for a simple system of messages.

```py
from torii.models import User


class Room(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                   related_name='rooms',
                                   blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='messages')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So when my user send a message I create a new `Message` object attached to my `Room`.
I want to query all `Room` for a given `User` and annotate **the date of the most recent message** and **the last message** in my query.

No problem to get the most recent date in my related messages using `Max` like this:

```py
for room in Room.objects.filter(users=user).annotate(last_message_date=Max('messages__date')).order_by('-last_message_date'): 
    print(room.__dict__)

{'id': 7, 'name': 'room-7', 'last_message_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 14, 0, 2, 118190, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
{'id': 9, 'name': 'room-9', 'last_message_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 8, 15, 19, 52, 343780, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
{'id': 8, 'name': 'room-8', 'last_message_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 7, 17, 18, 32, 648093, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

But I don't find any way to simply annotate the `content` of the last message. I have tried `Max('messages__content')` but in fact, it's order message by alphabetic order and it's always the same who is returned... I tried several subqueries with `F` and `Q` but that it didn’t work very well.

How can I annotate the result of `room.messages.last().content` directly with my query?

Comment: Why do you want to get one big query instead of using 3 for example?

Comment: I think there are several possibilities to approach things. I only try to make single access to my database by using all these performances, instead of realizing several simples requests which can't be concurrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem using `OuterRef` and `Subquery` documented [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

```py
from django.db.models import Max, OuterRef, Subquery 

newest = Message.objects.filter(room_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')

for room in Room.objects.filter(users=user)
                        .annotate(last_message_date=Max('messages__date'), 
                                  last_message=Subquery(newest.values('content')[:1]))
                        .order_by('-last_message_date'): 
    print(r.__dict__)
```

As I understand the behavior, we prepare beforehand `Subquery` by saying to use `id` of the element who call the subquery to `annotate` the filtred elements and order then by `-date`. So it returns the most recent element and we take the `value` of field `content` to annotate it.

This will create a complex but unique request using all the performance of the database.

Comment: You have the link to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and it's work great in production